# Stateless app - How to know if user is authenticated to show page

Tags: reactjs, spring-rest, stateless

Lets say that I have a React app, with a Spring REST API and I use a token based authentication. Now, lets say that I also use React-Router for the navigation.

I want to protect some pages of the app to be visible only to logged in users.

What I'm planning to do is to ask my server (Do a get request) in every page change if the user is authenticated and then give the appropriate data. If not, redirect to login

I believe this is the correct way to do it to be certain that my user is authenticated to view a page, but is there something better? I'm afraid if the call to every page is heavy. How other stateless rest APIs handle this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all that should be inaccessible to non-authorized users should be only in backend code - if page layout is public and you will only send data via API for authorized users, then it's OK to include page layout in React... though you don't need to send separate request to check if user is authenticated, just send to token with those requests that are asking for sensitive data

Answer (score 1):

I've done this implement with Laravel backend and VueJS frontend. A little different from React, but I think something is the same.

I used `JWT` (JSON Web Token), and create a login API. if the user logged in via login API, issue a token and response to the user. Then your frontend framework should keep the token at Cookie or local storage.

When your app would like to retrieve data from API, append the token to request header every time. You can decrypt the token from backend middleware as logged in user or not.

OK, this is how `JWT` and backend work. Back to your question, you can easily store a token and re-use it as user identifications as long as token is not expired.

Once the frontend page opened, send a request to the server API retrieving user's full name, account name or whatever you need for page rendering at least once. (Instead, if you've already stored that in local storage, just show it.)

Because of the token storing, you will know if the user logged in or not. So that you are able to handle some private, member only page from the frontend framework route. **But just for improving user experiences**. Check the token valid and user identification before retrieving and returning the sensitive data.

Comment: I thought of this solution, but my problem here is that how do you know if the token is expired? For example:
1) User logs in
2) Waits there for 15min
3) Then tries to go to another page

His token is expired in the server, but the client doesn't know that. So client will see that user once logged in and will render the page.

Comment: @klesgidis You are not able to know from frontend. You have to send it to backend then decrypt the token to know. Let's say there are 2 situations, first, if the token is expired and not valid anymore, your API should respond that the token is invalid, then handle the situation like redirect to login page or show message. Another, the token is invalid but can be refreshed, the server should issue a new one then respond within header. Then, update token you keep and use the new one next time.

Comment: I've seen your updated context, if you design an application like SPA (Single Page Application) and API server is where you data from, and you have checked the identification before retrieving data, don't worry about that guests get private contents. OK, like you said, if frontend framework renders private component accidentally, don't worry about that, because the expired token would fail the identity check, private data won't be responded even if member-only components were rendered. Users would just see a blank page. You need to care about is just user experiences (UX).

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in either local storage or session storage, that way you only have to make one initial call to the authorization server.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API